# java - replaceAll() returns PatternSyntaxException

Tags: java, replaceall, patternsyntaxexception

I have this code :

```
    buffer = buffer.replaceAll("(","");
```

That is returning `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException` I don't know why.
Help, please.

Comment: Do you know why you use `replaceAll` instead of `replace`?

Comment: because ``(`` is a special character .. also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715863/replace-all-method-throws-patternsyntaxexception

Comment: @Tom yes because I need to delete all occurences of "(" in this String.

Comment: @rev_dihazum what should I do then ?

Comment: *"yes because I need to delete all occurences of "(" in this String."* So you haven't even thought about reading the JavaDoc? Well, this is the perfect time to do it now. And then rethink if `replaceAll` is really the method you want to use. And _yes_ that "all" in `replaceAll` is misleading.

Comment: Java's naming is terrible here. `replace` should have been called `replaceAll` and that in turn `replaceAllOccurencesOfRegex` or whatever. Because that's what those methods actually do.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `replaceAll("(","")` with `replaceAll("\\(", "")`. `(` is a special character, you should paste `\\` before each of `\.[]{}()*+-?^$|`.

`"sta(c(k(overfl(ow".replaceAll("\\(", "") -> "stackoverflow"`

Comment: You should replace the answer with close vote as duplicate ...

Comment: @Tom, I've voted to close

Comment: This is good, but then don't answer it, as well. This is discouraged and can attract downvotes. Closing as duplicate exist to avoid "spreading" knowledge about a specific fact all other the place, which makes it harder to maintain it.